# Redirecting filtered requests to second web server

Tags: redirect, filter, iptables

What I want to do is setup two web servers. One will simply deliver normal content to people that request it and one will put minimal strain on the system and strictly deliver an access denied type of message for hackers.

I looked at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/ for ideas on how to create this redirection based on a bad IP address and its suggesting:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src <source address> -p tcp --dport <new server port number> -j REDIRECT --to-port <new server port number>
```

I then tested that theory by trying the following on a computer without internet but with apache server running on port 80 and nothing on port 81:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 81
```

I then typed in 127.0.0.1 in my web browser and received the same apache response as usual. Instead, I expected a browser message that it could not connect to the remote server.

How to I adjust the iptables command to make computers from listed IP in `--src` redirect from 127.0.0.1 port 80 to 127.0.0.1 port 81?

I understand I can use apache or php and even apache modules and all that for the redirection but I'm trying to use the least system-intensive approach and I want hackers to have the least amount of system resources available to them so that real visitors can enjoy a quality website, however

I want them to be able to see a message because if a real person gets blocked by accident then at least they can understand what's going on from an error message instead of a connection drop.

Answer (score 0):

Packets on the loopback interface (127.0.0.0/8) don't pass through the NAT tables. Try using an external computer for the test.